# Azure Pipelines Python FileNotFoundError in /home/vsts/work/1/

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to set up an Azure Pipeline in Python and am testing a single .py script with:
`- script: python Directory/Directory2/script_name.py`
I have some logging functionality in the script where I use logging.basicConfig to set the logging directory to:
`..Logs/file.log`
When I run the Azure Pipeline, I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/Logs/file.log'`
How can I get Azure Pipelines to write to the correct directory?

I also tried setting my working directory with:
`workingDirectory: Directory/Directory2/`

Comment: Could you please set the variable system.debug to true, then share the Python sample and full log with us?
According to the log, the file path should be /home/vsts/work/s/1/Logs/file.log

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to write to file which doesn't exist. So either you will handle this in your python script, or add this step before you run your python script:

```yaml
- bash: |
    mkdir directory
    touch directory/file
```

Comment: The directory does exist in my repository. The Python logging library is supposed to create a file if it doesn't exist. It works this way locally. The directory does exist in my example directory Directory/Directory2/Logs. I need it to write there instead of /home/vsts/work/1/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to traverse to an existing directory.
You could do something like this:

```
- script: |
    cd Directory
    dir # not necessary, will print all directories available
    pwd # will show your current path, also good for debugging
  displayName: 'Changing directory...'
```

To run the script itself, you'll need to do something like this:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath' # Options: filePath, inline
    scriptPath: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Directory/Directory2/script_name.py # Required when scriptSource == filePath
  displayName: 'Hello World'
```

After configuring pip and installing requirements, of course.